# Calculate values of coordinates in more system coordinates in same time, using unique tool

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, utm, xy

I have a table with several points. The attributes contain 3 "types" of coordinates in the SIRGAS2000 datum (decimal, DMS and UTM). I want to calculate these coordinates with a tool, because it is annoying to select zones(fuso) before calculating in UTM.

The answer can be in the model builder or Python. If it's in Python, please explain in detail (I'm still learning Python)

The format in longitude/latitude GMS(DMS) can be a little different.

[image]

I use ArcGIS

I want these coordinates only using the field shape.

I use another layer to know the zone (a zone class in DB), maybe can I use this layer to select and filter the points. the filter is ok. My problem is generate the coordinates using "calculate values" in model builder.

Comment: What format are you starting with and what are you converting to? If you're starting in DMS/DD, you can use the longitude value (and optionally the latitude if you have points on both sides of the equator) to calculate the zone. If you're starting from UTM, you have to know the zone.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? You mention "model builder" but do you mean the ArcGIS ModelBuilder or the QGIS Modeler?

Comment: What format are you starting with and what are you converting to?
No one, only the shape in lat/long Datum.

What GIS software are you using? 

ArcGIS

Comment: I use another layer to know the zone (a zone class in DB), maybe can I use this layer to select and filter the points. the filter is ok. My problem is generate the coordinates using "calculate values".